# “Unable to Start Oculus XR Plugin”

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, oculus, communityengine

I recently transferred my project over to a collaboration mode and it says “Unable To Start Oculus XR Plugin” when I try to test it. I made sure Oculus runtime was installed, I made sure the plug-in was up to date, I don’t know what else the issue could be! It is the only error i am getting in console.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall xr plugin, and then build the game.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Oculus official website also has instructions. Note: To support the XR Interaction Toolkit (ie VR function), it must be version 2019.4 or later. Ideally, choose a version with Long Term Support (LTS).
2. The best thing is to install an adb development environment on the computer
   2: Start configuring the Unity environment
3. Open Unity and convert it to the Android editing environment before importing the material, which can save time
4. Add XR related Unity packages to your project
   In the package manager, click Advanced > Show Preview Packages.
   Now find and install these three packages using the "Install" button in the lower right corner of the window:
   "XR Interaction Toolkit" package
   "XR Plugin Management" package
   "Oculus XR Plugin"
   3: Import the Oculus plugin
5. Search for "Oculus" in the store and import it into Unity
6. The Oculus menu will appear in the navigation bar, click -->PlatForm -->Edit Settings
   4: Unity connects to the Oculus headset
   Connect the Quest device to the computer using a USB cable. (As long as the computer has a USB port, the included charging cable will work.)
   Now that your Quest is plugged into your computer, take a look inside your VR headset.
   A popup may (or may not) appear asking you to "Allow USB Debugging". If so, click OK (Use the Oculus Quest's controllers.)
   Navigate back to "File>BuildSetting", then under "Running Device" to see if your device is recognized, refresh if not.
   5: Just use the Demo that comes with the plugin to package and test it
   Build And Run directly, otherwise, you need a software to install a third-party APK for Oculus

Answer (score 0):

in Unity, go to Edit -> Project Setting - > XR Plug-in Management

in the plug in providers section check in Oculus option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkW77.png)